# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined issue

Tags: php, pdo

I am very unsure at why I am getting such an error with my code

```
try {
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO table (path, title, era, information)
            VALUES (:path, :title, :era, :information)");
$stmt->bindParam(':path', $fname);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $Name);
$stmt->bindParam(':era', $Era);
$stmt->bindParam(':descrip', $Description);

// insert row
$stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo "Upload Successful";
}
```

I have tried so many different options and I just cant fix the error

```
$fname=$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
$Name =$_POST["name"];
$Era =$_POST["era"];
$Description =$_POST["info"];
```

these are the variables I used if that helps in solving my issue

Comment: `table` is a reserved word, so either change your table name or use backticks `\`table\``

Comment: Besides the invalid state error, `table` is a reserved word in MySQL  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the values `':path, :title, :era, :information'` in your `prepare` statement but try to set a value for the field `':descrip'` later on. Because this field is not defined in the `prepare` call you get that error.

Use `':information'` instead of `':descrip'`.

Comment: thank you for the help i Fixed that error but now i get this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table (path, title, era, information) VALUES ('a.png', 'asd', 'H' at line 1

Comment: @dave TABLE is an SQL keyword and can therefore not be used without escaping it with backslashes. Using \`table` will work.

Comment: @Dave help yourself, and give proper thanks (upvote and accept to close out this question).  Your comment above is material for another question, dont stack new questions as comments.